# Temporarily modifying `builtins` while splitting a django settings file

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, django-1.10

I'm starting a django 1.10 project and would like to split the settings file. I was unsatisfied with any existing solutions.

1. I do not want to be able to override `string`/`boolean`/`dict` settings from one file in another. Each `string`/`boolean`/`dict` setting should be set in only one place. This makes it easy to keep track of where things are defined.
2. I do not want to have to manually extend `tuple`/`list` settings, e.g. `INSTALLED_APPS += (test_app)`. This seems to be messy and requires me to keep track of whether a list or tuple was used in the other file.
3. I do not want to have to `import os` and define `BASE_DIR` in multiple files. DRY.

My solution, having looked at many others, is to replace `settings.py` with a directory containing `local_settings.py`, `common_settings.py` and `__init__.py`.

In `__init__.py`, I `import os` and calculate `BASE_DIR`. I then

```
import builtins
builtins.BASE_DIR = BASE_DIR
builtins.os = os

from .common_settings import *
from . import local_settings

# At this point both modules have run and we no longer need to be messing
# with the builtins namespace.
del builtins.BASE_DIR
del builtins.os
del builtins
```

I then loop over `dir(local_settings)` and mess with `globals()` to achieve the first two requirements (I can post the whole thing if requested but I'm interested in my use of `builtins`).

Is this use of `builtins` too evil? What can break it. Obviously if either identifier clashs with an attribute of a later version of `builtins`, then this code would break python. If a function that uses either of these identifiers ended up in one of the settings files and it was later called, then that would break.

I don't see either of those happening though. Is there a potential problem that I'm not seeing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The main problem with modifying `builtins` in this way is that it adds non-local reasoning to your code for no good reason.  The behavior of the common/local settings modules now implicitly depends on what happens in the module that imports them.  That's bad.

Essentially, you need to get rid of your requirement #3.

- Importing `os` in each module isn't "repeating yourself" because each module imports `os` into its own namespace.  That's just how Python works.
- You're right to want to only define `BASE_DIR` once, but the correct way to do this is to define the variable in one module (say `basedir.py`) and then explicitly import that variable (`from basedir import BASE_DIR`) into each module that uses it.